# Jquery each with where clause or similar

Tags: jquery, each

I have this bit of code

```
newDocumentState.documents = jQuery.grep(newDocumentState.documents,
    item => item["documentId"] !== docToRemove.name);

    $.each(newDocumentState.documents), (index, value ) => {
    this.documentState.addDocument(new DocumentMeta(value.documentId));
    });
```

I was wondering if I could have something like this or similar instead.

```
$.each(newDocumentState.documents.where(x => x.documentId !== docToRemove.name),
    (index, value ) => {
    this.documentState.addDocument(new DocumentMeta(value.documentId));
    });
```

Comment: You're looking for [`filtering`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Or the native [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as this seems to be an array, and nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: how work '=>' in your javascript?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      var docToRemoveName ="New";
      var documents =[ 
            {"documentId": "New", "class": "class1"},
            {"documentId": "New", "class": "class2"},
            {"documentId": "Close", "class": "class3"},
            {"documentId": "send", "class": "class3"},
            {"documentId": "receive", "class": "class3"}];

        $.each(documents.filter(
            function (el) { 
               return el.documentId !== docToRemoveName ;
            }), 
            function( index, value ) {
                alert( index + ": " + value.documentId );
            });
```

jsfiddle Link 
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9600/

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers I received, I came up with this

```
   $.each(newDocumentState.documents.filter(obj => obj.documentId !== docToRemove.name),
                    (index, value) => {
                        this.documentState.addDocument(new DocumentMeta(value.documentId));
                    });
```

It works. Tks.